# In $yz_{yy}=z_x-z_y$, what do $yz_{zz}$ mean?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I have to find the constant $c$ in order that the function $\displaystyle z= x^c e^{-y/x}$ proves the equation below:

> $yz_{yy}=z_x-z_y$

The problem is that I don't understand what $\displaystyle z_{yy}$ mean and what $z_x$ mean? Are they partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes they are partial derivatives.

Comment: In particular, $z_{yy}$ is the second partial of $z$ with respect to $y$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are partial derivatives. In particular, $z_{yy}$ is the second partial of $z$ with respect to $y$.

---

From the comments section: (Thanks goes to both `Cameron Williams` and `Ross Milikan)`